# jquery - best way to find an element with an id that matches another elements data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I use html's data- attribute on a list of menu links in order to tie the links to the div ids of sections of content I want to open when the links are clicked. So if I have a hidden div called "#section1" - the link that would open that link is .

Currently, in order to find the div that matches this link, I use jquery .each() to loop through all the possible elements, but it seems like there should be a better way.

Does anybody know how I could streamline this code and find the matching element without having to run the code in a loop?

Here's my code:

```
$('a.hidden_link').click(function(){
    section_ident = $(this).attr('data-ident');
    $('.hidden_section').each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).attr('data-ident') == section_ident){
            section_ref = $(this);
            section_ref.show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I am not sure I am right but can u try this $('#' + section_indent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
$('a.hidden_link').click(function(){
    $(".hidden_section[data-ident='"+$(this).attr('data-ident')+"']").show();
});
```

Jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/playerace/H7jwb/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.hidden_section[data-ident="' + section_ident + '"]').show();
```

all together:

```
$('a.hidden_link').click(function(){
    var section_ident = $(this).attr('data-ident');
    $('.hidden_section[data-ident="' + section_ident + '"]').show();
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `section_ident`? Please fix :-)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for [jQuery.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)!

```
$('a.hidden_link').click(function(){
    var section_ident = $(this).data('ident');
    $('.hidden_section').filter(function() {
        return this.attributes["data-ident"] == section_ident;
    }).show();
});
```

Comment: Why would you find all than filter when it could be done in one step?

Comment: So there's no reason to use filter in this case, it seems.

Comment: 2nd question today where X was faster in chrome and Y was faster in Firefox. Got to love it!

Comment: Actually, running http://jsfiddle.net/P9r9B/3/ in FF5, Chrome and IE9 yields better performance using filter() with a custom function. It's only in FF3.6 that all of the filter() approaches are much slower.